# Form closed but visible

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

Why a form is still visible after a FormClosed event is raised? How to detect when a form is *actually* closed?

[image]

Interesting part is that

```
_form2.VisibleChanged += (s, a) => 
{ 
    if (_form2.Visible == false) 
        MessageBox.Show("TEXT"); 
};
```

leads to the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing the dialog in an unusual way, the normal way it is done is by setting the form's DialogResult property.  Winforms does still synthesize the FormClosed event in this case but does it at the "wrong" time, the window is still visible.  It will go invisible immediately afterwards.

If you need a workaround for this then that's possible, the trick is to delay whatever you want to do in your FormClosed event handler.  That's elegantly done by using the Control.BeginInvoke() method, like this:

```
    _form2.FormClosed += (s, a) => {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("TEXT")));
    };
```

And you'll now see the MessageBox *after* the window disappeared.

Beware of the bug in your code, you subscribe the FormClosed event more than once.

Comment: That works only on a second Form. If it's the main Form called from `Program` by `Application.Run(new Form1());` - the MessageBox won’t show. [My question on the matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397177/how-to-execute-code-after-the-main-form-has-closed).

Comment: +1. I assumed I'm missing something. Why would a Form **Closed** event not fire _after_ the Form is closed. By your comment there I understood that's just how it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that you're showing a modal dialog - which prevents the UI thread from actually removing the form from the screen.

Comment: But how can the form be "_form2.Visible == false" and displayed on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Because the state of the property and what's drawn on screen don't necessarily match. You told your form to hide/close itself and the changing of the property means that the form "understood" what you want and "told" Windows to do so, but when the window manager actually repaints the screen so that the form actually gets out of the way is not under anyone's control. Also, by showing the `MessageBox` you're actually interrupting the flow of window messages that would actually cause the form to disappear visually.

Comment: Is there a way to determine when a modal form is removed from screen?

Comment: Well, usually the time when the form is hidden (=> the property changes) and the visual is removed from the screen lie very close together - if you don't interrupt the message flow. You could do two things: Put the action required not in the modal form's code, but after the call to `ShowDialog` in the calling code. Another solution would be to monitor and react to when the parent form is re-activated. But the real question is: what's your problem at all?

Comment: I want to show one form, close it, and then show second one. I cannot simply put my code after `ShowDialog ` because I want to close the first form from my eventhandler which is raised from an outside code.

Comment: The fact that I do not understand what you want to achieve leads me to the following comment: Maybe you should re-think you design...